# Is there a way to json serialize fields that aren't stored within a form in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, json, serialization

I am working on an Asp.net page and have fields that aren't organized inside a form.  Are there libraries that make it easier to serialize values to JSON elements that aren't in forms to a web method?

Comment: Well with a simple google search I found many ways, here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Comment: correct, but those are all assuming the data is in one form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might search for all inputs on the page or div and serialize them
using jquery :

```
jQuery.map($('input') , function(n, i){
      return {name:n.name,value:n.value};
    });
```

and then convert to json array using for example
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
by adding before

```
$.toJSON( jQuery.map($('input') , function(n, i){
          return {name:n.name,value:n.value};
        }));
```

Comment: After some searching this idea seemed to be the eventual outcome, was hoping there was some library already set in place.  Guess I can expand it to set element attributes on elements with bind properties and build something around that.  Thanks!